# Append queries as separate objects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called **Customers**. Customers have an *id* and a *name* and an *address*.

I have a table called **Orders**. Orders have an *id*, a *customerId*, and a *quantity*.

I have to implement a function that returns something like the following:

```
[{
    id: 123,
    name: "Jane Doe",
    address: "123 Fake Street",
    orders: [
        {
            id: 8,
            customerId: 123,
            quantity: 2
        },
        {
            id: 456,
            customerId: 123,
            quantity: 100
        }
    ]
}]
```

I'm using MySQL 5.6.11 and I suspect that this is a basic SQL question. Is this a JOIN? A UNION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a **join** between your Customers and Orders tables. 
If you only want customers that have orders, you will use an inner join.
If you want customers no matter if they have orders or not, use an outer join.

Example Inner Join:

```
SELECT Customers.Name, Customers.Address, Orders.Quantity
FROM
Customers 
INNER JOIN
Orders
ON Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId
```

Example Left Outer Join:

```
SELECT Customers.Name, Customers.Address, Orders.Quantity
FROM
Customers 
LEFT JOIN
Orders
ON Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.id,c.name,c.address,o.id,o.quantity 
from customer c, orders o 
where o.customerId = c.id;
```

this will return;

123,Jane Doe,123 Fake Street, 8,8
123,Jane Doe,123 Fake Street, 456,100

pull the data you want from that.